# how to easily connect dozens of bigquery table to gsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery

I have a dataset in bigquery containing dozens of tables. The business wants to access these tables through a connected gsheet

The gsheet UI only allows connecting tables one by one, this is a bit tedious. Is there an alternative way to connect all the tables in the dataset to individual sheets with the same gsheet document in one go?

Answer (score 1):

The UI only allows one by one but you can also use the Sheets API to add data sources. You could build your own app and send the requests to the API as [`AddDataSourceRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddDataSourceRequest). An easier way would be to use Apps Script since it's already connected with Sheets and it also has a [`DataSourceTable`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table) class. A quick example of how to add a data source in Apps Script would look like this:

```js
function addConnectedTable() {
  SpreadsheetApp.enableBigQueryExecution();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var spec = SpreadsheetApp.newDataSourceSpec()
             .asBigQuery()
             .setProjectId('your-billing-project') //set your own project ID here
             .setRawQuery('select * from `bigquery-public-data.new_york_trees.tree_species`')
             .build();
  
  ss.insertDataSourceSheet(spec).asSheet().setName("Some Name"); //sets the name of the new sheet
}
```

As a sample I used a query from a public data set, but you can just write your own queries for each of your tables and run the script with them to quickly add them.

##### Sources:

- [Sheets API AddDataSourceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddDataSourceRequest)
- [Connected Sheets in Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/connected-sheets)
- [Apps Script DataSourceTable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-source-table)